# Array item is not mutable

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to solve [557 on leetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-words-in-a-string-iii/) with two pointers, and I found a strange behavior, which I cannot explain.

Below is my code

```
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @return {string}
 */
var reverseWords = function(s) {
    // return s.split(" ").map(w => w.split("").reverse().join("")).join(" ")
    let arr = s.split(" "), w
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        let x = arr[i], left = 0, right = x.length - 1, holder = null
        while(left < right){
            holder = x[left]
            x[left] = x[right]
            x[right] = holder
            left += 1
            right -= 1
        }
    }
    return arr.join(" ")
};
```

and example `"Let's take LeetCode contest"`

while I can move the while loop to a function and solve it in a different way, I'm not sure why x is not changing, from my understanding this is an array item and can be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the variable "x" is not an array but a String which comes from the variable "arr" to make it work you need to change

```
let x = arr[i]
```

to

```
let x = arr[i].split("")
```

the correct code is:

```
var reverseWords = function(s) {
    // return s.split(" ").map(w => w.split("").reverse().join("")).join(" ")
    let arr = s.split(" "), w
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        let x = arr[i].split(""), left = 0, right = x.length - 1, holder = null
        while(left < right){
            holder = x[right]
            x[right] = x[left]
            x[left] = holder
            left += 1
            right -= 1
        }
        arr[i] = x.join("");
    }
    return arr.join(" ")
};
```

Comment: I guess I need to stop solving Algo before sleeping